# Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (7,) but got array with shape (4,)

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I made a CNN classifier of 7 classes. I am training a sequential model, here

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(C1, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(3*C1, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(6*numPCAcomponents, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))
```

Then I am compiling the model:

```
sgd = SGD(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Then evaluating a test set using this model. The problem is here. When I am starting mode.evaluate function this error comes:

```
Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (7,) but got array with shape (4,)
```

The way I am evaluating is here,

```
Y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
target_names = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']

classification = classification_report(np.argmax(y_test, axis=1), y_pred, target_names=target_names)
confusion = confusion_matrix(np.argmax(y_test, axis=1), y_pred)
score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=32)
Test_Loss =  score[0]*100
Test_accuracy = score[1]*100
```

Why this error is coming and how can I solve this error?I checked everything many times but can't find the fault.

Comment: What's the shape of X_test? Seems its not correct.

Comment: @matias Shape of X_test is 1380X25X5X5 and shape of training set was 107731X25X5X5. There are member of four class in test set. I think here's the problem.

Comment: What about y_test? If you trained a model with 7 classes, you cannot test it for only four.

Comment: But I need to. What can I do then? Even my test image can have only 1 class. @Matias

Comment: You cannot do much, what exactly are the seven and four classes? Are they related, or completely different? Please add more details.